# How to get the summation of each of the 2 elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example the list is:

```
stuff = [1, 2, 5, 7]
```

Now I created a new list named `sum_list` to store the summation of each of the 2 elements in `stuff`. The element in the `sum_list` will be 1+2, 1+5, 1+7, 2+5, 2+7, 5+7:

```
[3, 6, 8, 7, 9, 12]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one hideous list comprehension:

```py
[a + b for i, a in enumerate(my_list, start=1) for b in my_list[i:]]
```

Nested loops may be clearer:

```py
result = []
for i, a in enumerate(my_list, start=1):
    for b in my_list[i:]:
        result.append(a + b)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `itertools.combinations` to get all the combinations of 2 elements, and `sum` to sum them:

```
>>> stuff = [1, 2, 5, 7]
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> [sum(c) for c in combinations(stuff, 2)]
[3, 6, 8, 7, 9, 12]
```